# aquireTokenSilent in msal Angular failing with Azure Custom Polices

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We have custom policies for Azure B2C with MFA enabled.
After successful login, when trying to acquire access token using `acquireTokenSilent()`, getting the below errors

> Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxxxx/oauth2/authresp&response_type=code&scope=email+profile&login_hintXXXXXXXXXXX' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
> Followed by ClientAuthError: Token renewal operation failed due to timeout.

or

> AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'

I am getting these errors after every login. If I try to call `acquireTokenPopup()`, the popup is showing the MFA flow again and asking to authenticate the phone number which is not desired.

I have read many posts regarding these but unable to fix the issue.

Google technical profile:

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="Google-OAUTH">
      <DisplayName>Google</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">google</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email profile</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_GoogleSecret" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="loginHint" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" PartnerClaimType="prompt" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:account_prompt}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
      </InputClaims>

      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="google.com" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="requiresMFA" DefaultValue="true"/>  
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isAccessFlow"  DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:access_flow}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt"  DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:account_prompt}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Phone Factor Technical profile:

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
          <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor1.1</Item>
            <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

MFA related orchestration steps:

```
           <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>requiresMFA</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isAccessFlow</Value>
               <Value>true</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>newPhoneNumberEntered</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

requiresMFA and isAccesssFow are two custom attributes i am using.

- requiresMFA to stop MFA for few providers
- isAccessFlow is to avoid MFA in acquire token popup.I am passing this in request object from frontend while calling acquireTokenPopup when silent calls are failing with any of the above errors.

Please let me who how i can avoid getting those errors. These attributes i used as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Post your MFA and Google technical profiles and MFA orchestration step. Session management is likely incorrectly configured and you also are being blocked by the Google select account screen.

Comment: @JasSuri, Thanks for responding, I have edited my question with the profiles and orchestration steps. Please check and let me know.

Comment: If anyone can help me out, please do comment . I'm trying badly to fix this.